# Writing a many-to-many query for common table attributes

Tags: mysql

It's been a long time since I've worked directly with MySQL, so for fun, I have a MySQL database of train information, based off the NYC Subway system. I have a `Station` table and `Route` table, and there is a many-to-many relationship between the two.

What I want to do is find out which stations two or more different routes have in common. I'm trying different join techniques but none of them seem to be working (I probably have the syntax wrong).

So for example, I want to see which stations serve both routes "1" and "2" (i.e., which stations do these routes have in common?).

```
mysql> describe station;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(45) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> describe route;
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(4) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The table between them is called `RouteStation` that has ID's for each of the two tables.

The query I want is to find the names of the stations that serve any group of routes. So in this example, I want to find the names of the stations that serve both routes "1" and "2".

```
SELECT Station.name FROM Station
    JOIN RouteStation ON (Station.id = RouteStation.stationId)
    JOIN Route ON (Route.id = RouteStation.routeId)
WHERE Route.name = "1" AND Route.name = "2";
```

I know there is probably an issue with the last part because it's not possible for the route name to be "1" and "2" at the same time, but I hope that the gist of what I'm looking for is clear enough.

EDIT: RouteStation schema:

```
mysql> describe routestation;
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| stationId | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| routeId   | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Can you show us also the `RouteStation` schema? Thanks

Comment: @KaeL I edited the question to show the schema.

Comment: @SameerMirji it keeps returning an `Empty set`. It works with individual route names (e.g. just "1" or just "2"), and if I put `OR` instead of `AND`, it just gives me everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this one:

```
SELECT name
    FROM station
    WHERE id IN (
        SELECT RS.stationId
            FROM RouteStation RS
            WHERE RS.routeId IN (1, 2)
            GROUP BY RS.stationId  
            HAVING COUNT(RS.routeId) > 1
    )
```

Instead of using `AND`, you should use the `OR` keyword: `routeId = 1 OR routeId = 2`. It is the same with `IN` keyword.

After that, we used `GROUP BY stationId` so we can `COUNT` the `routeIds` because we need only the stations which are `HAVING` more than 1 routes.